# Python setuptools install as editable

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I am packaging a python app with setuptools, typically running `python setup.py install` And it packages everything into an egg and installs it.

The problem is I want it to be installed as editable, so I can go into site-packages and make changes to the app source code. I haven't yet found out how to do it yet.

On my previous work environment, running `python setup.py install` would copy the source folder to the site-packages, but this time it doesn't do it.

Comment: I managed to do it by running `pip install -e ./` inside the app project folder, and I think this is better approach because it links back to the development folder. But I would still like to find out how to do it by running `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
python setup.py develop
```

like described [here](http://www.siafoo.net/article/77#install-vs-develop).

Comment: The link goes missing now.